# Exchange Server Distribution List

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

I have created a distribution list in exchange that allow certain people from my company to receive emails from a particular email address. An example would be if you send an email to "blank@esi.com" then the people added to the distribution list would also receive it. Now I want to add some modification to this distribution list. If any Subject field of any incoming emails contains the phrase "RT" (without the quotes), send a copy of that email to "blank@tid.com". How can we achieve this?

I am currently using window server 2012 & Exchange 2013

Comment: Hi, welocome to Stackoverflow! can you tell us which MX-server you are using?

Comment: @Prajwal admin exchange server 2012

Comment: There is no "Exchange Server 2012" there exist only an Exchange 2013 which can be installed on Windows 2012. So I think you are using 2013

Answer (score 0):

You can use transport rules for this. In the GUI you go to Mail Flow, then Rules. When you add a rule you can select when it applies and what should happen when it does. In your case I would use "if subject or body includes (RT)" then "bcc message to.. (blank@tid.com)"